# How to achieve this footer

Tags: html, css

I'm absolutely blank, I'm trying to achieve a footer with text to the left and an image to the right which is a litter tall.

Please see image, you will see the text and a square to show where the image will be placed:

[image]

Really appreciate your help guy's

Comment: And what HTML are you trying to work with? Whereabouts is it that you're stuck? Have you attempted anything as yet; what's going wrong in your attempt(s)?

Comment: If you still haven't tried anything try and then come back. Stack Overflow is here to help with problems your encountering, not to write your code for you

Comment: Sorry guys I'm a little bit of a novice and just wanted an idea how to attempted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done according to your image, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/PPBGj/)

```
<footer>
  <span>YOUR AMBITION REALISED</span>
  <img src="/" alt="Image"/>
</footer>


footer {
  background: #722F8E;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 140px 0 0 70px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #fff;
}
img {
  background: #fff;
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 0 80px 0 0;
  border: 3px solid #111;
}
```

Comment: Thank you mdesdev I really appreciate you help on this one god bless.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely position both elements inside a relative positioned container  like so... Adjust height and dimensions as necessary.

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <span>Text here</span>
    <img src="file" alt="" width="" height="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}

#footer span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

#footer img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```